# Custom 404 error page for stopped websites on IIS

Tags: iis-7.5

When you stop a website on IIS and you try to surf to the binded URL, you get a general 404 error page. As one would expect.

But is there a way to edit this page/or set a custom page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, if you stop the site, that means the IIS will not listen the IIS site's port.

So the request will not send to the IIS, IIS will not return any response to the client. The server refused the connection.

In my opinion, there is no way to set the a custom page by IIS.